# One SOAP request/response sent to two endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, soap

I'm wondering the best solution to the below:
There are two identical SOAP asmx webservices written in C# on separate IIS servers (wsdl are the same)
(for FYI: One (A) writes to Oracle and the other (B) writes to SQLServer)
Responses are returned to the requestor (error messages, success and such)
So now the requestor has 2 endpoints - everything is good

The problem now is the requestor can only have one endpoint.
The endpoint being A only.  I am being told my management to modify the (A) webservice code to pass-through request/response to the (B) webservice.

Is this the best solution?  Would this be a good use for IIS ARR (Application Request Routing)? It is not installed on the server.  I'm thinking it might be as simple as modify the config files..?  Management is telling me to modify the A code (an MVC solution) but I'm thinking there is a slick solution for this.

Has anyone done something like this and could share knowledge or links to examples?
The environment is Windows Server 2016 all within same domain.  I can't seen to find much on ARR or maybe I'm not understanding ARR. Or maybe that is completely over-blown solution.

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: The way I have handled that in the past is I knew what vendor was SOAP AND another a REST  and based off that on my data layer I would complete  the request to endpoint based on that with a switch statement that’s one solution I’m sure there many others as well

Comment: i don't think ARR can fan out request payloads - it is designed to route one request to one backend server based on request properties. What is the logic for deciding which service you want to hit?

Comment: ARR is usually used for load balancing, I think your scenario does not need to use ARR. You can use URL Rewrite to meet your needs.

Comment: Or you might have a look into BPEL engines, they do webservice orchestration (what you're doing here - can't tell you if they are overblown or not): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BPEL_engines